# Assinar xml Nfse paulistana

Tags: c#, xml, certificado-digital, assinatura-digital, xmldocument

Eu fiz um programa em `C#` que assina o `XML` em lote da nota legal de Porto Alegre. Agora a empresa em que trabalho abriu uma filial em São Paulo e preciso assinar o XML em lote da nota fiscal paulistana para declarar serviços prestados. Tentei usar o mesmo programa que fiz e obtive um erro:

> "Malformed reference element."

Reparei algumas diferenças entre os xmls. O xml de São Paulo não tem o atributo id nem nas tags rps nem no lote. O atributo id é obrigatório para o elemento reference que computa a assinatura. Tentei setar manualmente o id, mas deu o mesmo erro.

Outra diferença que notei é que na nota legal de Porto Alegre há elementos "InfRps", e cada um precisa de um elemento `signature`, com todos os dados de como foi feita a assinatura, como o algoritmo, etc. O lote também precisa do elemento signature. Na nota fiscal paulistana, o lote no fim do arquivo precisa o elemento signature, mas os elementos RPS que equivalem aos "InfRps" da nota legal de Porto Alegre contém apenas uma tag assinatura, com uma codificação em `base64` da assinatura do elemento RPS. Não sei ainda como gerar essa assinatura.

Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Abaixo há um exemplo de como deve ficar o lote de xml da nota fiscal paulistana já assinado:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PedidoEnvioLoteRPS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/nfe">
<Cabecalho Versao="1" xmlns="">
<CPFCNPJRemetente>
  <CNPJ>04642554000143</CNPJ>
</CPFCNPJRemetente>
<transacao>false</transacao>
<dtInicio>2007-01-20</dtInicio>
<dtFim>2007-01-20</dtFim>
<QtdRPS>2</QtdRPS>
<ValorTotalServicos>2000</ValorTotalServicos>
<ValorTotalDeducoes>200</ValorTotalDeducoes>
</Cabecalho>
<RPS xmlns="">
       <Assinatura>ro6Og7L5BMPpYZKXfSSITNe8U9C4a95P9dIspX8R0Okg1CRsA87N08Llaq+q6IVOGLhjGMkAELBIkQ8T0BGR3czgtJAuOcgMlOmGZlgziWAg3Kww3pFD+rYxE+DRgL2M5QXTaZEYwVNj0lZyJpt1nS9LHUqO7PB+ivYRk+ewUVA=</Assinatura>
<ChaveRPS>
  <InscricaoPrestador>31000000</InscricaoPrestador>
  <SerieRPS>LLLLL</SerieRPS>
  <NumeroRPS>1</NumeroRPS>
</ChaveRPS>
<TipoRPS>RPS-M</TipoRPS>
<DataEmissao>2007-01-20</DataEmissao>
<StatusRPS>N</StatusRPS>
<TributacaoRPS>T</TributacaoRPS>
<ValorServicos>1000</ValorServicos>
<ValorDeducoes>100</ValorDeducoes>
<CodigoServico>2658</CodigoServico>
<AliquotaServicos>0.05</AliquotaServicos>
<ISSRetido>false</ISSRetido>
<CPFCNPJTomador>
  <CPF>18564071878</CPF>
</CPFCNPJTomador>
<RazaoSocialTomador>PATRICIA TUPYNAMBA</RazaoSocialTomador>
<EnderecoTomador>
  <TipoLogradouro>R</TipoLogradouro>
  <Logradouro>Guararapes</Logradouro>
  <NumeroEndereco>495 A</NumeroEndereco>
  <ComplementoEndereco>ap 102</ComplementoEndereco>
  <Bairro>BROOKLIN PAULISTA</Bairro>
  <Cidade>3550308</Cidade>
  <UF>SP</UF>
  <CEP>4561000</CEP>
</EnderecoTomador>
<EmailTomador>ptupynamba@prodam.sp.gov.br</EmailTomador>
<Discriminacao>Desenvolvimento de Web Site Pessoal</Discriminacao>
</RPS>
<RPS xmlns="">
            <Assinatura>jkTucEqcj8Qkes8RalHZW+p6Zc6weeqnPabOK7IHSkyVTO9reNqpMclEh8n6nHXSPGcn   svhQx4JWx/sK26IxVTOMKp3i41/1w3OyC9SvL0VPtzrARKQMEqTf2kqwu9skHMzw5d4T/jfjYLrp5n/Y    AbMqKQ5zaa4qAcY0A066OAc=</Assinatura>
<ChaveRPS>
  <InscricaoPrestador>31000000</InscricaoPrestador>
  <SerieRPS>LLLLL</SerieRPS>
  <NumeroRPS>2</NumeroRPS>
</ChaveRPS>
<TipoRPS>RPS-M</TipoRPS>
<DataEmissao>2007-01-20</DataEmissao>
<StatusRPS>N</StatusRPS>
<TributacaoRPS>T</TributacaoRPS>
<ValorServicos>1000</ValorServicos>
<ValorDeducoes>100</ValorDeducoes>
<ValorPIS>10</ValorPIS>
<ValorCOFINS>20</ValorCOFINS>
<ValorINSS>30</ValorINSS>
<ValorIR>40</ValorIR>
<ValorCSLL>50</ValorCSLL>
<CodigoServico>2658</CodigoServico>
<AliquotaServicos>0.05</AliquotaServicos>
<ISSRetido>false</ISSRetido>
<CPFCNPJTomador>
  <CNPJ>06215299000188</CNPJ>
</CPFCNPJTomador>
        <RazaoSocialTomador>Grixco Soluções</RazaoSocialTomador>
<EnderecoTomador>
  <TipoLogradouro>R</TipoLogradouro>
  <Logradouro>Augusta</Logradouro>
  <NumeroEndereco>01642</NumeroEndereco>
  <ComplementoEndereco>3 Andar</ComplementoEndereco>
  <Bairro>Cerqueira Cesar</Bairro>
  <Cidade>3550308</Cidade>
  <UF>SP</UF>
  <CEP>1304001</CEP>
</EnderecoTomador>
<Discriminacao>Manutenção de Sistema</Discriminacao>
</RPS>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
  <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
  <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
  <Reference URI="">
    <Transforms>
      <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
      <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
    </Transforms>
    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
    <DigestValue>AkHyCjCwkANg3aRAnltAXR1YQ4c=</DigestValue>
  </Reference>
</SignedInfo>   
<SignatureValue>IkLB0qfZLDuTNXNB83tXXsZ2TFNK9X0l7gq8jRCOcwhit059iF5gNHfmuM4NoUhyhZ+rC6UGn9lSMv1A35lofsplIuWUJO13yPtHsxaY6/rP9DTB4Ve3ihzwrEkpenANoEU1C5wLenX0lRtYc1k3fWeDmZUvv+b/M81pwoPBL8k=</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
  <X509Data>
    <X509Certificate>MIIFUzCCBDugAwIBAgIQSUJS8pELZyjasDkgGzKm0TANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBuMQswCQYDVQQGEwJCUjETMBEGA1UEChMKSUNQLUJyYXNpbDEsMCoGA1UECxMjU2VjcmV0YXJpYSBkYSBSZWNlaXRhIEZlZGVyYWwgLSBTUkYxHDAaBgNVBAMTE0FDIENlcnRpU2lnbiBTUkYgVjMwHhcNMDYwNzE5MDAwMDAwWhcNMDkwNzE4MjM1OTU5WjCB1DELMAkGA1UEBhMCQlIxEzARBgNVBAoUCklDUC1CcmFzaWwxKjAoBgNVBAsTIVNlY3JldGFyaWEgZGEgUmVjZWl0YSBGZWRlcmFsLVNSRjETMBEGA1UECxQKU1JGIGUtQ05QSjELMAkGA1UECBMCUkoxFzAVBgNVBAcUDlJJTyBERSBKQU5FSVJPMUkwRwYDVQQDE0BUSVBMQU4gQ09OU1VMVE9SSUEgRSBTRVJWSUNPUyBFTSBJTkZPUk1BVElDQSBMVERBOjA0NjQyNTU0MDAwMTQzMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCx86LAoJRVmtQMzmtdWpyNgKy200+bwjtz/TuywNcTjvfw7qHFGIgTjipmuZ3zhX28CgYLYXp3tj1Dfh2B7EhjHdLJPfvoF4MgbN/dQGXmGpMpF5cNxYusOGCZiyASvI7Gqt/xE4xLSIalNr6kF6CaPLkpFgTNNe+WQkG0fMqsQQIDAQABo4ICCDCCAgQwgbEGA1UdEQSBqTCBpqA/BgVgTAEDBKA2DDQyNDA3MTk3NjA3MTM4NTM3Nzg2MDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwOTI5OTA2MjFDTkggIFJKoB8GBWBMAQMCoBYMFEZFUk5BTkRPIFNJTFZBIEJSQUdBoBkGBWBMAQMDoBAMDjA0NjQyNTU0MDAwMTQzoBEGBWBMAQMHoAgMBjIzOTU0OIEUZmJyYWdhQHRpcGxhbi5jb20uYnIwCQYDVR0TBAIwADBiBgNVHR8EWzBZMFegVaBThlFodHRwOi8vaWNwLWJyYXNpbC5jZXJ0aXNpZ24uY29tLmJyL3JlcG9zaXRvcmlvL2xjci9BQ0NlcnRpU2lnblNSRlYzL0xhdGVzdENSTC5jcmwwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAU9p1ZXf6/xXLN3c7ELmYbLu4Iz3YwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgXgMFUGA1UdIAROMEwwSgYGYEwBAgMGMEAwPgYIKwYBBQUHAgEWMmh0dHA6Ly9pY3AtYnJhc2lsLmNlcnRpc2lnbi5jb20uYnIvcmVwb3NpdG9yaW8vZHBjMB0GA1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMEBggrBgEFBQcDAjA4BggrBgEFBQcBAQQsMCowKAYIKwYBBQUHMAGGHGh0dHA6Ly9vY3NwLmNlcnRpc2lnbi5jb20uYnIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAC5w/CBXAykvPSbBGf+u0UPcWVJATL2ix0hCfNUVtHaCjMz8hRjgYqmhpefzDm2LCTvoCPzG6XQBYxAmnDhX1f/gyjHz+E1xJg451qtqcyCJ9861o9R2bHd4zR0DuyxCNGOTiYJ4Gc/Xa4xqECorAx5ktkk1T/HOc1K/ntRGpdL+llsO/jqSRmTOnRgdeNHcKkyXsOgL5BwxxgGNuIyqirgGXW0by4Io1GnSXtixxfvEOnqOicxBY6AcVS9HHuhmOBYiK9skAUp0Sm2v41hpsC8uIkfUeRxsJIp2CNZ4DjoyfmKwNLMCRZQAKpwMXyyHZlX1a4o/9iGTszNeeShw61g=</X509Certificate>
  </X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
</PedidoEnvioLoteRPS>
```

Segue abaixo o programa que fiz para assinar a nota legal de Porto Alegre:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace escolhercertificadosimples
{
    public static class DocumentExtensions
    {
        public static XmlDocument ToXmlDocument(this XDocument xDocument)
        {
            var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            using (var xmlReader = xDocument.CreateReader())
            {
                xmlDocument.Load(xmlReader);
            }
            return xmlDocument;
        }

        public static XDocument ToXDocument(this XmlDocument xmlDocument)
        {
            using (var nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDocument))
            {
                nodeReader.MoveToContent();
                return XDocument.Load(nodeReader);
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Abre o deposito de certificados da maquina local
            var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            //var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            //Abre a tela de escolher certificado
            var selectedCertificate = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(
                store.Certificates,
                "Title",
                "MSG",
                X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);

            //Pega o objeto x509 do certificado selecionado
            foreach (X509Certificate2 x509 in selectedCertificate)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Imprime informações do certificado, se existirem
                    byte[] rawdata = x509.RawData;
                    //Console.WriteLine("Content Type: {0}{1}", X509Certificate2.GetCertContentType(rawdata), Environment.NewLine);
                    //Console.WriteLine("Friendly Name: {0}{1}", x509.FriendlyName, Environment.NewLine);
                    //Console.WriteLine("Certificate Verified?: {0}{1}", x509.Verify(), Environment.NewLine);
                    //Console.WriteLine("Simple Name: {0}{1}", x509.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, true), Environment.NewLine);
                    //Console.WriteLine("Signature Algorithm: {0}{1}", x509.SignatureAlgorithm.FriendlyName, Environment.NewLine);
                    //Console.WriteLine("Private Key: {0}{1}", x509.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(false), Environment.NewLine);
                    //Console.WriteLine("Public Key: {0}{1}", x509.PublicKey.Key.ToXmlString(false), Environment.NewLine);
                    //Console.WriteLine("Certificate Archived?: {0}{1}", x509.Archived, Environment.NewLine);
                    //Console.WriteLine("Length of Raw Data: {0}{1}", x509.RawData.Length, Environment.NewLine);
                    //X509Certificate2UI.DisplayCertificate(x509);
                    //x509.Reset();


                    //==============================
                    // Comeca a ler os arquivos xml
                    //==============================
                    var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles("./", "*.xml");
                    //Console.WriteLine(txtFiles.Count());break;
                    foreach (string currentFile in txtFiles)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Lendo o arquivo" + currentFile + ":");

                        var originalDoc = XDocument.Load(currentFile);

                        //string id = xe4.FirstAttribute.Value.ToString();
                        //Console.WriteLine(id);
                        //Console.WriteLine(xe4.ToString());


                        XmlDocument doc = DocumentExtensions.ToXmlDocument(originalDoc);

                        //====================================
                        // Comeca a Criacao da pasta Assinados
                        //====================================
                        // Specify the directory you want to manipulate.
                        string path_originais = "Originais";

                        try
                        {
                            // Determine whether the directory exists.
                            if (Directory.Exists(path_originais))
                            {
                                //Console.WriteLine("That path exists already.");
                                //Console.WriteLine("Pasta Assinados já existe.");
                                //return;
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                // Try to create the directory.
                                DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path_originais);
                                Console.WriteLine("The directory was created successfully at {0}.", Directory.GetCreationTime(path_originais));
                            }
                            // Delete the directory.
                            //di.Delete();
                            //Console.WriteLine("The directory was deleted successfully.");
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
                        }
                        finally { }

                        //doc.Save(path + "/teste.xml"); //break;

                        //Salva o novo arquivo assinado na pasta Assinados
                        doc.Save(path_originais + "/" + currentFile.Replace("./", "")); //break;






                        //==============================
                        // Comeca a Leitura das Notas
                        //==============================
                        XmlNodeList ListInfRps = doc.GetElementsByTagName("RPS");
                        //Console.WriteLine(ListInfRps.Count); break;


                        //Console.WriteLine("Aqui");

                        //Console.WriteLine(ListInfNFe);

                        //SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);

                        //Console.WriteLine(ListInfRps.Count);

                        int NodeCounter = 1;

                        foreach (XmlElement InfRps in ListInfRps)
                        {
                            Console.Write("Assinando Nota " + NodeCounter + "...") ;
                            //Console.WriteLine(InfRps.InnerXml);
                            //continue;

                            //Console.WriteLine(InfRps.Value);

                            //string id = InfRps.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Id").Value;
                            //Console.WriteLine(id);
                            string id = "lote";

                            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(InfRps);

                            signedXml.SigningKey = x509.PrivateKey;
                            //RSACryptoServiceProvider privateKey = x509.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

                            // Transformações p/ DigestValue da Nota
                            //Reference reference = new Reference("#" + id);
                            Reference reference = new Reference("#" + id.Replace(":",""));
                            //Console.WriteLine("#" + id.Replace(":", ""));
                            //Reference reference = new Reference("#" + "lote");

                            reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());

                            reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigC14NTransform());

                            signedXml.AddReference(reference);



                            KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
                            keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(x509));
                            signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;



                            signedXml.ComputeSignature();



                            XmlElement xmlSignature = doc.CreateElement("Signature", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");

                            XmlAttribute attr = doc.CreateAttribute("Id");
                            attr.Value = "Ass_" + id;

                            //Add the attribute to the node     
                            xmlSignature.Attributes.SetNamedItem(attr);

                            XmlElement xmlSignedInfo = signedXml.SignedInfo.GetXml();
                            XmlElement xmlKeyInfo = signedXml.KeyInfo.GetXml();



                            XmlElement xmlSignatureValue = doc.CreateElement("SignatureValue", xmlSignature.NamespaceURI);
                            string signBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(signedXml.Signature.SignatureValue);
                            XmlText text = doc.CreateTextNode(signBase64);
                            xmlSignatureValue.AppendChild(text);
                            //xmlSignature.AppendChild(xmlSignatureValue);



                            xmlSignature.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlSignedInfo, true));

                            xmlSignature.AppendChild(xmlSignatureValue);

                            xmlSignature.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlKeyInfo, true));


                            //InfRps.AppendChild(xmlSignature);

                            XmlNodeList ListRps = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Rps");
                            //Console.WriteLine(ListInfRps.Count); break;


                            //Console.WriteLine("Aqui");

                            //Console.WriteLine(ListInfNFe);

                            //SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);

                            int RpsCounter = 1;

                            foreach (XmlElement Rps in ListRps)
                            {

                                //Console.WriteLine(Rps.InnerXml); return;
                                //Console.WriteLine(RpsCounter);
                                //Console.WriteLine(NodeCounter);

                                if (RpsCounter == NodeCounter)
                                {
                                    Rps.AppendChild(xmlSignature);
                                }
                                RpsCounter++;
                            }

                            Console.WriteLine("Ok");
                            NodeCounter++;
                        }





                        //==============================
                        // Comeca a Leitura do Lote
                        //==============================
                        XmlNodeList ListLoteRps = doc.GetElementsByTagName("PedidoEnvioLoteRPS");
                        //Console.WriteLine(ListInfRps.Count); break;


                        //Console.WriteLine("Aqui");

                        //Console.WriteLine(ListInfNFe);

                        //SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);

                        foreach (XmlElement LoteRps in ListLoteRps)
                        {
                            Console.Write("Assinando Lote...");

                            //Console.WriteLine("Aquiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii");
                            //Console.WriteLine(InfRps.InnerXml);
                            //continue;

                            //Console.WriteLine(InfRps.Value);

                            string id = LoteRps.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Id").Value;
                            //Console.WriteLine(id);

                            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(LoteRps);
                            //Console.WriteLine("1");
                            signedXml.SigningKey = x509.PrivateKey;
                            //RSACryptoServiceProvider privateKey = x509.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
                            //Console.WriteLine("2");
                            // Transformações p/ DigestValue da Nota
                            Reference reference = new Reference("#" + id);
                            //Reference reference = new Reference("#" + "lote");
                            //Console.WriteLine("3");
                            reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
                            //Console.WriteLine("4");
                            reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigC14NTransform());
                            //Console.WriteLine("5");
                            signedXml.AddReference(reference);

                            //Console.WriteLine("6");

                            KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
                            keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(x509));
                            signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

                            //Console.WriteLine("7");

                            signedXml.ComputeSignature();

                            //Console.WriteLine("8");

                            XmlElement xmlSignature = doc.CreateElement("Signature", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");

                            XmlAttribute attr = doc.CreateAttribute("Id");
                            attr.Value = "Ass_"+id;

                            //Add the attribute to the node     
                            xmlSignature.Attributes.SetNamedItem(attr);

                            XmlElement xmlSignedInfo = signedXml.SignedInfo.GetXml();
                            XmlElement xmlKeyInfo = signedXml.KeyInfo.GetXml();

                            //Console.WriteLine("9");

                            XmlElement xmlSignatureValue = doc.CreateElement("SignatureValue", xmlSignature.NamespaceURI);


                            string signBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(signedXml.Signature.SignatureValue);
                            XmlText text = doc.CreateTextNode(signBase64);
                            xmlSignatureValue.AppendChild(text);
                            //xmlSignature.AppendChild(xmlSignatureValue);

                            //Console.WriteLine("10");

                            xmlSignature.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlSignedInfo, true));

                            xmlSignature.AppendChild(xmlSignatureValue);

                            xmlSignature.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlKeyInfo, true));


                            //LoteRps.AppendChild(xmlSignature);

                            XmlNodeList ListEnviarLoteRpsEnvio = doc.GetElementsByTagName("EnviarLoteRpsEnvio");
                            //Console.WriteLine(ListInfRps.Count); break;


                            //Console.WriteLine("Aqui");

                            //Console.WriteLine(ListInfNFe);

                            //SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);

                            foreach (XmlElement EnviarLoteRpsEnvio in ListEnviarLoteRpsEnvio)
                            {
                                EnviarLoteRpsEnvio.AppendChild(xmlSignature);
                            }


                            Console.WriteLine("Ok");

                            //Console.WriteLine(InfRps.InnerXml);


                            //XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
                            //XmlNode myNode = root.SelectSingleNode("descendant::LoteRps");
                            //myNode.AppendChild(xmlSignature);


                            //====================================
                            // Comeca a Criacao da pasta Assinados
                            //====================================
                            // Specify the directory you want to manipulate.
                            string path = "Assinados";

                            try
                            {
                                // Determine whether the directory exists.
                                if (Directory.Exists(path))
                                {
                                    //Console.WriteLine("That path exists already.");
                                    //Console.WriteLine("Pasta Assinados já existe.");
                                    //return;
                                }
                                else
                                {

                                    // Try to create the directory.
                                    DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                                    Console.WriteLine("The directory was created successfully at {0}.", Directory.GetCreationTime(path));
                                }
                                // Delete the directory.
                                //di.Delete();
                                //Console.WriteLine("The directory was deleted successfully.");
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
                            }
                            finally { }

                            //doc.Save(path + "/teste.xml"); //break;

                            //Salva o novo arquivo assinado na pasta Assinados
                            doc.Save(path + "/" + currentFile.Replace("./","")); //break;



                            //Console.WriteLine("11");

                            //Encoding enc = Encoding.UTF8;
                            //MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                            //XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(ms, enc);

                            //Console.WriteLine("12");

                            //writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                            //writer.Indentation = 2;
                            //writer.Namespaces = true;

                            //Console.WriteLine("13");

                            //doc.WriteTo(writer);
                            //writer.Flush();
                            //writer.Close();

                            //Console.WriteLine("Aquiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii");
                            //Console.WriteLine(writer.Namespaces);






                            //XmlWriterSettings oSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                            //oSettings.Indent = true;
                            //oSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;
                            //oSettings.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;

                            //XmlWriter writer1 = XmlWriter.Create("xmlfile.xml", oSettings);
                            //System.Xml.XmlElement xml = InfRps;
                            //xml.WriteContentTo(writer1);



                            //signedXml = new SignedXml(infNFe);
                            //signedXml.SigningKey = ObtemCertificado().PrivateKey;
                        }

                        //signedXml.SigningKey = x509.PrivateKey;
                        //signedXml.SignatureMethod;

                        //Console.WriteLine(signedXml.SignatureMethod);
                        //Console.WriteLine(signedXml.Signature);
                        //break;
                    }
                }
                catch (CryptographicException ce)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ce.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("Information could not be written out for this certificate.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tive esse mesmo problema.

Para resolver basta passar o ID em branco.

Por padrão o `URI` no reference vem `NULL` basta passar `string.Empty` e tudo fica certo.